# How to load fragment data only when its tab is clicked in PagerSlidingTabStrip

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am using `PagerSlidingTabStrip` in my project and am showing data in fragments. Its a great library which works great. Each Fragment consists of a scholar's lectures which are loaded from a web service. The code to access the web service is in `onCreateView` method of the Fragment. Currently all the fragment's data is loaded at the same time when they are added to `ViewPager`. I was wondering if there is any way of loading the Fragment's data only when a user clicks/swipes to a specific tab. Not everything at a time.

Current code is pretty standard, I took help from the provided example [android solution].[1](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

Pager Adapter is as follows:

```
public class ScholarDetailPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String[] TITLES = { "Scholar Info", "Lectures"};
    Scholar _scholar;

    public ScholarDetailPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Scholar scholar) {
        super(fm);
        _scholar = scholar;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        if(arg0 == 0)
            return ScholarsInfoFragment.netInstance(_scholar.Name, _scholar.Information, _scholar.ThumbnailUrl);
        else
            return ScholarLecturesFragment.newInstance(_scholar.ScholarId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

}
```

It returns TWO fragments, Info and Lectures. Lectures fragment calls a web service to get a scholar's lectures.

Activity code is:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set the Above View
    setContentView(R.layout.tabbed_view);
    Scholar scholar = getScholar(getIntent());      

    _tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    _pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    _adapter = new ScholarDetailPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), scholar);

    _pager.setAdapter(_adapter);

    final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics());
    _pager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);

    _tabs.setViewPager(_pager);
}
```

I tried adding `_tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(this);` and ended up having `onPageSelected(int arg0)` in my activity as well. I thought It would be easy now. Then I modified `public Fragment getItem(int arg0)` in `ScholarDetailPagerAdapter` above and returned `null` instead of returning two fragments. But that raised an exception. I thought It would render empty views in pager .. but of course I was wrong.

To make sure Fragment loads data when its respective tab is clicked and is visible, I also have tried overriding its following events and wrote the data loading call in them:

1. `onResume()` Not worked. Still loads data when added in activity
2. Tried overriding onHiddenChanged

   ```
   @Override   
   public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {

       super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);

       if(!hidden){
           loadLectures();
       }
   ```

   }

This did not work too. No data loaded as if this event is not fired at all.

How do I do that? I simply want to load a fragment when user clicks on a tab.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You could override `setUserVisibleHint` event of the fragment to know if its visible to the user and then load your data. something like following:

```
boolean _areLecturesLoaded = false;

@Override
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
     super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
     if (isVisibleToUser && !_areLecturesLoaded ) {
      loadLectures(); 
      _areLecturesLoaded = true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: What if you are injecting a child fragment in the `onCreateView` function?  I am not wanting my `MapFragment` to load the `SupportMapFragment` until the tab is actually clicked.

Comment: Is it safe to call  `getContext()` in this method?

Comment: @Zapnologica i try and there was an exception null object

Comment: it wont work for me, I have only two tabs in my View Pager

Answer (score 1):

```
private boolean isLoaded =false,isVisibleToUser;

@Override

public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    this.isVisibleToUser=isVisibleToUser;
    if(isVisibleToUser && isAdded() ){
        loadData();
        isLoaded =true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  if(isVisibleToUser && (!isLoaded)){
        loadData();
        isLoaded=true;
    }
}
```