# How to integrate interstitial ad in 2nd tab?

Tags: android, admob

I'm creating an app having 2 tabs and Ad Mob, my question is how can I integrate interstitial ad in 2nd tab ? , means as per google [AdMob policy](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287) Placing an interstitial ad after every user action is restricted, though I want to add fullscreen Ad when I swipe from 1st Tab to 2nd Tab and restrict the Ad when I swipe from the 2nd tab to 1st tab. How can I do that? **Guide me with examples and corrections!** Below is my current activity.

```js
boolean firstResume = true;

 private ViewPager viewPager;
 private FBTabsAdapter mAdapter;
 private ActionBar actionBar;
 Handler handler1 = new Handler();
 private Context context;
 private int i = 0;
 private boolean exitAds = false;
 // private Fragment _fragment;

 // Tab titles
 private String[] tabs = { "TAB 1", " TAB 2" };

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  if (!firstResume) {

  } else {
   firstResume = false;
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
 }

 @Override
 public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
  // on tab selected
  // show respected fragment view
  viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
  if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
   Log.e("UPDATED", "DOWNLOADS SELECTED");
   final DownloadsFragment fragment = ((DownloadsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
     .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":1"));
   fragment.updateDownloads();

   // if (i == 0) {
   // i++;
   // } else if (i > 0) {
   // }

  } // else
   // displayInterstitial();
 }

 @Override
 public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }
```

TABS ADAPTER

```js
package xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.com;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


public class ABTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ABTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                // Top Rated fragment activity
                return new TAB1Fragment();
            case 1:
                // fragment activity
                return new TAB2Fragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 2;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: First create activity and create 2 fragments(TAB1,TAB2) and make connection to the fragment to activity.before create interstitial ads ID

Comment: Firstly keep the ad loaded as soon as parent container activity is created
then get the context of the container activity in the page adapter and as soon as the fragment of your choice is selected show the ad.. should be simple as that :)

Comment: @ vadivel @shadygoneinsane , hi ,can you show me some examples?

Comment: check the position of tab in `onTabSelected` method and show the interstitial ads based on the current position of the tab

Comment: Have you created two different fragments ? If you could the simply load your Ads in second `TAB2` fragment in `onCreateView()` method. Another way is to detect position of `TAB2` in `onTabSelected` method. @AgathaJannet

Comment: @Amrut Bidri  @ Piyush, I have updated my code please check it

Comment: You should go through [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20347665/5134647) and use `setUserVisibleHint` event to load an add..

Comment: @AgathaJannet My question is that if you'r calling two different fragments then load your ads in second fragment when your fragment completely load. _setUserVisibleHint_ will do your work.

Comment: Check [http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/) @AgathaJannet

Comment: @AgathaJannet have you checked link ?

Comment: @ Piyush, I have checked it, but I didn't get anything, can you show me some example with an ad in it? I'm new to this things, though .  Please check the updated tabs adapter code.